# $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $x\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: infinity

If i have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}s_{n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ like a sequence and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, Do $x$ and $n$ tend to the same infinity?  i do not know if my question is well asked, i think the answer is yes, both are very large numbers on the same line, some idea or explanation thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Infinity is not a number; the notation simply means increasing without bound

Answer (score 3):

If you consider $\mathbb N$ as a subset of $\mathbb R$, then yeah, kind of.  For any $n\in \mathbb N$, there is a $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $x>n$, and for all $x\in\mathbb R$ there is a $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n>x$.

So if you were to adjoin an element called $\infty$ to the real line such that $\infty=\sup\mathbb R$ (as we often do), then that same $\infty$ would be the supremum of $\mathbb N$ as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if we consider the definition of limit we can say that $x$ and $n$ tend to $\infty$ according to the same definition since for any $M$ such that

- $\exists x_0\quad\forall x\ge x_0 \implies x\ge M$
- $\exists n_0 \quad\forall n\ge n_0 \implies n\ge M$

Anyway, pay attention to the fact that the ways $x$ and $n$ tend to $\infty$ are not equivalent, indeed let consider for example

$$f(x)=\sin(2x\pi), \quad f(n)=\sin(2n\pi)=0$$

Comment: I don't think this is what OP was asking.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Why not, if $n$ and $x$ would tend to $ \infty$ in the same way the limit should be the same.

Comment: OP asked if the "infinity" in both limits were the same, not about whether the limit themselves are equal.

Comment: @79037662 Yes I get tour point, indeed I've added something more. Anyway I think it is important to point out that the two ways are not equivalent.